# How do I write a pandas dataframe to Vertica?

Tags: python, pandas, vertica

I have some data set in a pandas data frame that I wish to write to Vertica. I've already created my table using the vertica_python library. What is the best way to write my data frame to Vertica?

Comment: Possible solution - https://community.vertica.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/Writing-Pandas-dataframe-to-vertica/m-p/227918

Comment: Hm, it looks like they point towards this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vertica-sqlalchemy/0.1 , but it is quite untested. Any other thoughts on potential solutions? I'm leaning towards I guess doing a row-by-row edit with jinja2 templates, but that doesn't seem very pythonic to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when connecting to Vertica, you can use Postgresql as a stand-in since certain parts of Vertica were originally based on Postgresql.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@host:5433/MYDB')
df.to_sql('table_name', engine)
```

If this doesn't work you could try out the vertica-sqlalchemy package.

Also, depending on the SQL created (and if the ODBC driver converts `INSERT` to a `COPY`) this might be very slow.  If you find that it is doing lots of individual inserts on the database, you'll probably want to switch to a `COPY` method where you create strings and `COPY FROM STDIN` to make it faster.