# Creating table based on pandas dataframe structure

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic, vertica

I need to create a table in the database based on the columns in dataframe (python pandas). I want to be able to do this in python :

```
create table new table 
as 
select * from old_table
```

I generally first create a table with this statement :

```
cursor.execute("create table if not exists table name ( column details..)")
```

In this case, the columns in dataframe could be different each time. Is there a way to create the table structure in vertica based on dataframe structure?

There is a method : `to_sql` but this method is for mysql and sqllite , it does not work for Vertica. Any other ways to create a table in vertica?

Comment: `to_sql` method might be of help?

Comment: @John Galt : any examples would help...the reason I want to make it dynamic is..some of the metrics (which are columns) might change and hence I need to be able to create a table based on dataframe structure itself

Comment: @John Galt : to_sql method is not valid for vertica, as per the documentation it is valid only for sqllite and mysql. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I write a pandas dataframe to Vertica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973328/how-do-i-write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-vertica)

Comment: @dogwyn : that post does not solve my issue. any other method/way you can suggest for this?

Comment: Sorry, no. Don't have any experience with Vertica.

Comment: `to_sql` uses sqlalchemy, and can support any database flavour that is supported by sqlalchemy (so it is not only for mysql and sqlite). For using Vertica with sqlalchemy, see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832487/connecting-to-vertica-database-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: sqlalchemy has changed my life :)