# Python pandas dataframe to vertica table using vertica-python

Tags: python, pandas, vertica

I am using python to communicate with vertica. Is there an elegant way to create a new vertica table with a pandas dataframe. I am using vertica-python 0.6.14. The only way I know is to use a for loop to write each row of the dataframe into vertica. Also it is very painful to create the table in vertica since you need to know the datatype of each column. I was wondering if there is a simple solution that takes care of everything, before commiting to the for loop.

I tried using the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://user:pass@host:5433/MYDB')
df.to_sql('mytable', engine)
```

It creates a table but does not fill it and I am getting an error message.

I also tried via DSN, by installing the driver and configureing a DSN. Then I used this line:

```
engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://username:password@mydsn')
```

I can communicate with vertica but pandas -> vertica still won't work. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29973328/2901002)

Comment: Already tried, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Thought there might be something new out there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use copy statement to insert data from Pandas data frame to Vertica:

```
import vertica_python
conn_info = {'host': host,
             'port': port,
             'user': user,
             'password': password,
             'database': database,
             # 10 minutes timeout on queries
             'read_timeout': 600,
             # default throw error on invalid UTF-8 results
             'unicode_error': 'strict',
             # SSL is disabled by default
             'ssl': False,
             'connection_timeout': 30
             # connection timeout is not enabled by default
            }
df_csv = df.to_csv(sep=',',index=False)
cols = tuple(df.columns)
with vertica_python.connect(**conn_info) as connection:
    cur = connection.cursor('dict')
    cur.copy("""COPY yourtable {}
                from stdin DELIMITER ',' """.format(cols),
             df_csv)
```

Comment: So in this example the table has to be in the database already? If not than how does Vertica now which formats to assign to each column?

Comment: @valenzio On Vertica cluster I worked with `COPY {table} (columns) FROM STDIN /LOCAL...` raise error if I try to copy to a non-existing table i.e. `COPY` doesn't create table. I think you can write a python function to generate create table command based on pandas dataframe dtypes and execute the command through cur.execute. create table based on a df and copy df into the table.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working I had to add install the vertica-python module from Condaforge.

Where as Redsift, MySQL and MSSQL work with a simple connection string

```
def _get_generic_connection(self):
    """
    Creates a connection that can be used directly by the sqlalchemy library.

    Returns: A sqlalchemy database connection

    """
return create_engine(<<your connection string>>)
```

You have to do something like the following

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import vertica_python

    def _get_vertica_connection(self):
        """
        Creates a connection appropriate for HP Vertica based on the vertica_python library.

        Returns: A vertica_python database connection

        """
        conn_info = {'host': <<your host>>,
                     'port': << Vertica port>>,
                     'user': << appropriate user >>,
                     'password': << appropriate password >>,
                     'database': << your db name >>,
                     # 10 minutes timeout on queries
                     'read_timeout': 600,
                     # default throw error on invalid UTF-8 results
                     'unicode_error': 'strict',
                     # SSL is disabled by default
                     'ssl': False,
                     'connection_timeout': 300
                     # connection timeout is not enabled by default
                     }
        return vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
```

I have a class that has those two functions plus

```
def __init__(self, app_config):
    """

    Args:
        app_config( ApplicationConfiguration): Object to handle the configuration of the system
    """
    self._app_config = app_config
    self._platform = app_config.db_server.db_platform
    self._connection_function_dict = {
        "vertica": self._get_vertica_connection,
        "redshift": self._get_generic_connection,
        "mssql": self._get_generic_connection
    }

def get_db_connection(self):
    """
    Acts as the public method to retrieve a database connection for use by Pandas.
    Returns: A database connection of a type dictated by the database platform

    """
    db_connection = self._connection_function_dict[self._platform]()

    if db_connection is None:
        raise NameError("Database platform \"{}\" not known".format(self._platform))

    return db_connection
```

This is sufficient to produce a working connection to any of the platforms we use and SQLAlchemy is happy with those connections.  That means you can then do

```
pandas.read_sql(<<your SQL query>>, << your connection>>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your submission. I haven't tried it yet, but scanning over your code, it seems it does sql-to-pandas. Or am I misstaken. I am trying to get a pandas dataframe into a vertica table. I am confused by this line `pandas.read_sql(<<your SQL query>>, << your connection>>)`.

Answer (score 0):

i sometimes do a df.to_csv and then

```
    copy_cmd = /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U <user> -d <db> --password='password' -h <host> -c "COPY schema.table(col1,col2) FROM LOCAL 'path/to/your.csv'  PARSER fcsvparser(header='true')"

    os.system(copy_cmd)
```

this works for me , if you want to capture exception or rejected rows also you can use copy cmd like this

```
     copy_cmd = /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U <user> -d <db> --password='password' -h <host> 
     -c "COPY schema.table(col1,col2) FROM LOCAL 'path/to/your.csv'  PARSER 
     fcsvparser(header='true') DIRECT REJECTMAX 1000   EXCEPTIONS 'path/to/exception.csv' 
     REJECTED DATA 'path/to/rejected.csv'"
```